# Deployment systems for Linux

Tags: patch, deployment

My project is based on a Raspberry Pi distro - Raspbian. But I made changes to it. There are a lot of them: changes in config.txt, adding system services, installing new packages, change the image of the splash screen, etc. But every time when I need a new, "fresh" system I need to repeat all these changes. Are there some automated tools to perform this? Also, I want to supply these changes to my potential users, to make deployment of my changes easy on their side.

Comment: Lots of choices. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code#Community_content

Comment: @MarkPlotnick This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's raspbian-based (which is basically a tweaked debian) the easiest way would be to build your own .deb package with, in the `postinst` script, will do the modification on the fresh system.

Then you only have to create your own .deb mirror (very easy as long as you have access to a webserver), add the mirror to your sources.list and `apt-get install <your package>`

If you want to do new modifications, then just release an update of your package and `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

Your project could be anything - "all these changes" is what you have to define, automate and then make easy for users to run. A package also has to be defined (dependencies, scripts). You's have to offer it in different formats.